# How to properly use querySelectorAll with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, dom

What's the proper way to use the querySelectorAll method? I'm just trying to add a click event to each div with class '.box', but it's not working. I've found that this works fine if I replace the method with 'getElementById' and just test the kitchen box.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.box').addEventListener('click', test);

function test() {
  console.log('hi');
}
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <div class="box" id="kitchen"></div>
  <div class="box" id="laundry"></div>
  <div class="box" id="bedroom"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Use console.log to see what `querySelectorAll` outputs. It will give you insight on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really simple, you just loop over every element and add an event listener.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.box').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    // Handle the click event here
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll()` returns an NodeList object which you can treat as an array.
You have to loop on every element and add event listener on every one of them separately.